# How to use yahoo UI in my page

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, yui

I need to include any dll in my asp.net project?.Is that good to use in web page my page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few server-side options, [there's a project on codeplex for a few wrapped controls as asp.net controls](http://yuidotnet.codeplex.com/) or the [YUIAsp.Net library](http://www.yui-asp.net/), if that's what you're after.

For general usage, you just need to include the library in the page and go from there, you can host it on your site or use a CDN:

- [Use the YUI Config to generate script includes](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/hosting/)
- [Or, include the loader from Google's CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#yui)

As for others, I'd check out [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and possibly [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/), there are others, but after a lot of testing, I settle on jQuery personally, it's clean/concise and tons of community support, that doesn't mean you should rule out others though, [**see what's best for you**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks),

Answer (score 0):

YUI is a javascript framework. You do not need any serverside stuff like a DLL for it.
It is good for your web page if you like to work with it and if it does what you need.

Some alternatives would be jQuery+jQueryUI or ExtJS.